# regular expression for exact number in a numerical string

Tags: regex, regexp-like

I have been trying to create a regular expression for the following problem:

```
 A)  PAR
 B)  1234
```

given strings A and B above, i want to find all matches where those values occur in order regardless of white space, etc with the following important rules:

1. both strings A and B cannot exist as a substring to another larger string
2. the given string B must occur after A
3. the given string B must occur by itself and not be a part of another number

here are some example potential matches:

1. **PAR****1234**
2. **PAR** **1234**
3. **PAR** 5678, **1234**
4. **PAR** 9991234999, **1234**
5. **PAR** !@#-= **1234**
6. **PAR****1234**-122
7. **PAR**#**1234**-233
8. ANY TEXT **PAR**#**1234**-233

however, the following should not match:

1. **PAR**T **1234** - PAR is substring of PART
2. A**PAR**T **1234** - PAR is substring of APART
3. **PAR** **1234**999 - 1234 is substring of 1234999
4. **PAR** 999**1234** - 1234 is substring of 9991234
5. **PAR** 999**1234**999 - 1234 is substring of 9991234999
6. **1234** **PAR** - 1234 occurs before PAR

unfortunately, i am trying to do this using [REGEXP_LIKE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php) in oracle and there is no \b

i tried

\W***PAR**\W***1234**

but that won't match #3 in the potential matches above.  so ive attempted many variations that will work for some but not all.

i was wondering if there is an expression that could capture what i am trying to accomplish.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Would this work? PAR.*1234

Comment: not exactly, because that would also return #1-5 in the results that should not match

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses `\b` to check for a [word boundary.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
\bPAR1234\b|\bPAR\b.*\b1234\b
```

See the demo here: https://regex101.com/r/SM8Bq1/2